# Popup window does not dismiss on ouside touch when set mPopWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null)

Tags: android

I have 1 question/ issue, I have implemented Popup window in my project. I have check list in pop up window and having mandatory selection functionality. For this functionality I need to check whether user had selected any at least 1 item in list on back press,before dismiss of pop window. The problem is onKey listener fire only when I set   mPopWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null); to my popup window. but at this time outside touch does not work at all. If remove mPopWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null); and put mPopWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable()); outside touch works but onBack press does not fire onKey listener. Any 1 know how to achieve both functionality onBackpress and outsid touch on popup window.

Comment: you have to close popup window..

Comment: Yes I need to close Pop up window, onbackpress and on outside touch. but problem is that when we set mPopWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable()); poup dismiss in both condition(onbackpress and on outside touch) but not getting any event like onKey on onbackpress where i can check whether user selected at least one selection from list or not . But when set mPopWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null); onKey fire but outside touch doesn't work.

Comment: @Abhi Try to put some code on how you have implemented popUp window. That would help.

Comment: mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
  mWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  mWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  mWindow.setTouchable(true);
  mWindow.setFocusable(true);
  mWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
  mWindow.setContentView(mRootView);
  mWindow.getContentView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Answer (score 0):

ok,I solved this problem.

change:
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

to:
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

bingo.